# Trying to pass tag value of UIImageView to viewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, xib, touchesbegan

I have two UIImageView's in my application, both of which when touched, are to call the same viewController.  However, I am trying to figure out a way to distinguish the call made by one UIImageView from the other, and I figure that by giving each UIImageView a tag value would be the way to go.

Now that I have done this, I am trying to figure out how to actually pass it when I call the required viewController?  Please bear in mind that the viewController I am calling is created from a .xib file, and is being called from an application built in storyboards.

Here is my method that instantiates and calls the viewController from the UIImageView:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    
    _nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_nextView setDelegate:(id)self];
    [_nextView setSignatureDelegate:self];
    NextNavigationController *navigationController = [[NextNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_nextView];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}
```

As I mentioned, when I make the call to display the viewController, I would like somehow to pass the tag value from the calling UIImageView as well.  The tag value for each UIImageView I set in IB via the attributes inspector. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a UIButton instead of a UIImageView? There is an action method called when a button is pressed. It passes along the button, so you could also check its tag in that action method. You would just need to make it a custom button which you assign an image.

Comment: That's actually an interesting possibility that I haven't thought of.  I may have to consider it if my current approach doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `touches` set contains instances of `UITouch` objects. Use the `touch.view` property to determine the view object in which the touch originally occurred. Once you have that reference, you can get that view's tag value.

But do consider making these `UIButton` instances as Jamie mentions in the comments.